# why does and EBS volumes mounted in an Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance as /dev/sdh1 appear as /dev/xvdh1?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mount, amazon-ebs

When mounting an EBS volume on ubuntu specified as /dev/sdh1 it actually mounts it at /dev/xvdh1. The aws console still thinks it's mounted at /dev/sdh1 so it took a while to realize that it was actually mounted, just in the wrong place

I ran into this problem a long time ago using ubuntu on ec2. I just ran into it again

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/post!reply.jspa?messageID=351382

and it seems like I'm not alone:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=68957&tstart=0

I haven't found a good answer as to why this happens or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing broken, so there's not really anything to "fix". This change (`/dev/sdX` to `/dev/xvdX`) was made in recent kernel versions (perhaps the 3.x tree? I can't recall specifically at the moment). EC2 hasn't yet changed their terminology to reflect the change in device naming conventions, as that would confuse all those who are running older kernels. Eventually I suspect they'll make the change, but it could be a while.